# WinForms UserControl inheritance in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: .net, winforms, inheritance, compact-framework, user-controls

The full .Net framework has an inherited UserControl but this option isn't offered by Visual Studio when creating a new control in a Compact Framework project.

Manually changing the ancestor class of a user control to another user control results in an exception being thrown by the designer when subsequently trying to open it.

Anyone know if user control inheritance is possible?

Comment: You tried all of these things? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458/whats-the-state-of-play-with-visual-inheritance/49526#49526

Comment: Nothing works - the designer doesn't seem to support inheritance of user controls. The fact that there's no inherited user control in a mobile project hints that it's not possible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some notes on CF UserControls in [this blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/10/30/ProjectResistanceFormPaintingAndCommentsOnTheStudioDesigner.aspx).  The short of it is "Unless you plan to be a control vendor don't bother wasting your time even trying to get designer support working."

Comment: Thanks, I gave up and went for splitting things up into user controls and reusing them, rather than subclassing. Even that is a PITA though, as I often get exceptions in the designer and have to fiddle around to fix things. VS seems very fragile in this area :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've had success *running* inherited controls but absolutely none within the designer.  I've had to set the parent as **Control** to use the designer and then set it to my parent control prior to deploying (after closing the designer).

Comment: Good suggestion, but the whole idea of control inheritance in this case is to use the form designer so that I can add other controls in the subclass and line them up with those in the base class.

I think I'll switch to composition rather than inheritance...